# wp_schedule_event() in plugin not scheduling a cron event

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, cron

I'm creating a WordPress plugin, when the plugin is activated I need a cron job to be scheduled to run every 5 minutes.

Here's my code;

```
// Register plugin activation hook
function my_plugin_activate() {
    if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_function_hook' ) ) {  
       wp_schedule_event( time(), '5', 'my_function_hook' );  
    }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_activate' );

// Register plugin deactivation hook
function my_plugin_deactivate(){
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('my_function_hook');
}
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__,'my_plugin_deactivate');

// Function I want to run when cron event runs
function my_function(){
    //Function code
}
add_action( 'my_function_hook', 'my_function');
```

When I use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/ to check the cron events, nothing has been added, I'm expecting a cron event to be added that runs 'my_function' at 5 minute intervals, I have no errors

Comment: WordPress cron is not the same as the cron on the server. For it to be run, you need to visit the page (you or anybody else) otherwise it won't run ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See: [`wp_schedule_event()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/)

> Valid values for the recurrence are hourly, daily, and twicedaily.
>   These can be extended using the ‘cron_schedules’ filter in
>   wp_get_schedules().

So you just need to add a custom schedule that runs every 5 minutes.

```
<?php // Requires PHP 5.4+.

add_filter( 'cron_schedules', function ( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every-5-minutes'] = array(
        'interval' => 5 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS,
        'display'  => __( 'Every 5 minutes' )
    );
    return $schedules;
} );

if( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_function_hook' ) ) {  
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every-5-minutes', 'my_function_hook' );  
}
```

Comment: I'm aware WordPress cron works differently - this was the issue, I passed the wp_schedule_event() function a number rather than a valid schedule, thanks for your help jaswrks

Answer (score 3):

WP Cron runs, when somebody visits your website.
Thus if nobody visits, the cron never runs.

Now there are 2 solutions:

1. Disable WP Cron, use a real cron job and customize it.

https://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/wordpress/how-to-replace-wordpress-cron-with-a-real-cron-job

2. Use a custom interval in `wp_schedule_event()`:

   ```
   function myprefix_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
       $schedules['every_six_hours'] = array(
           'interval' => 21600, // Every 6 hours
           'display'  => __( 'Every 6 hours' ),
       );
       return $schedules;
   }
   add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'myprefix_custom_cron_schedule' );

   //Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
   if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'myprefix_cron_hook' ) ) {
       wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_six_hours', 'myprefix_cron_hook' );
   }

   ///Hook into that action that'll fire every six hours
    add_action( 'myprefix_cron_hook', 'myprefix_cron_function' );

   //create your function, that runs on cron
   function myprefix_cron_function() {
       //your function...
   }
   ```

and you can see these tuts

http://www.nextscripts.com/tutorials/wp-cron-scheduling-tasks-in-wordpress/

http://www.iceablethemes.com/optimize-wordpress-replace-wp_cron-real-cron-job/

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/16/schedule-events-using-wordpress-cron/

custom Wp cron

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/cron_schedules

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/16/schedule-events-using-wordpress-cron/

http://www.viper007bond.com/2011/12/14/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-cron-intervals/

http://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-wordpress-cron/

https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-cron-jobs/

http://www.paulund.co.uk/create-cron-jobs-in-wordpress

cron linux

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800

[google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=wp%20cron%20job%20wih%20real%20cron%20job&oq=wp%20cron%20job%20wih%20real%20cron%20job&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.21049j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=wp%20cron%20job%20with%20real%20cron%20job&spell=1)

Answer (score 0):

As @dingo_d commented, WordPress Cron doesn't work like server Cron. the WordPress Cron runs on page load. It checks the database for a scheduled event and if an event is scheduled it runs the task. So if nobody visits the website in a 5 minute time period *no* job will be run in that period. When someone *does* visit the website, the page load process runs and the scheduled event takes place.

It was setup like this so WordPress would work without needing any particular Cron functionality on the server.

To circumvent this you can use a service that automatically visit your website or you could setup a Cron script on your server to automatically load the page.

Assuming a linux server you ssh into the terminal then write `crontab -e` and hit enter. You'll enter the cron file for setting up cron jobs. Add to the file the following line:

```
/5 * * * wget -q -O - http://yourdomain.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron
```

substituting `http://yourdomain.com` for your actual website. This ensures your website is visited every 5 minutes.

I grabbed the information on how to do this from https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-cron-jobs/ so credit to him and that link has lots more WordPress cron info.